# Bar chart not rendering in react using the nivo library

Tags: reactjs

I can't seem to get nivo's bar charts to show up even though I'm following the docs. The doc is here: https://nivo.rocks/bar/

Below is the code, essentially the same as the docs except I added the parent `div` tag to add the `height` as mentioned by [React js: Nivo Pie chart not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52872500/react-js-nivo-pie-chart-not-showing-up):

```
// install (please make sure versions match peerDependencies)
// yarn add @nivo/core @nivo/bar
import React from 'react'
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { ResponsiveBar } from '@nivo/bar'

// make sure parent container have a defined height when using
// responsive component, otherwise height will be 0 and
// no chart will be rendered.
// website examples showcase many properties,
// you'll often use just a few of them.
const BarChart = ({ data /* see data tab */ }) => {
  console.log(data)
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400 }}>
    <ResponsiveBar
        data={data}
        keys={[
            'hot dog',
            'burger',
            'sandwich',
            'kebab',
            'fries',
            'donut'
        ]}
        indexBy="country"
        margin={{ top: 50, right: 130, bottom: 50, left: 60 }}
        padding={0.3}
        valueScale={{ type: 'linear' }}
        indexScale={{ type: 'band', round: true }}
        colors={{ scheme: 'nivo' }}
        defs={[
            {
                id: 'dots',
                type: 'patternDots',
                background: 'inherit',
                color: '#38bcb2',
                size: 4,
                padding: 1,
                stagger: true
            },
            {
                id: 'lines',
                type: 'patternLines',
                background: 'inherit',
                color: '#eed312',
                rotation: -45,
                lineWidth: 6,
                spacing: 10
            }
        ]}
        fill={[
            {
                match: {
                    id: 'fries'
                },
                id: 'dots'
            },
            {
                match: {
                    id: 'sandwich'
                },
                id: 'lines'
            }
        ]}
        borderColor={{
            from: 'color',
            modifiers: [
                [
                    'darker',
                    1.6
                ]
            ]
        }}
        axisTop={null}
        axisRight={null}
        axisBottom={{
            tickSize: 5,
            tickPadding: 5,
            tickRotation: 0,
            legend: 'country',
            legendPosition: 'middle',
            legendOffset: 32
        }}
        axisLeft={{
            tickSize: 5,
            tickPadding: 5,
            tickRotation: 0,
            legend: 'food',
            legendPosition: 'middle',
            legendOffset: -40
        }}
        labelSkipWidth={12}
        labelSkipHeight={12}
        labelTextColor={{
            from: 'color',
            modifiers: [
                [
                    'darker',
                    1.6
                ]
            ]
        }}
        legends={[
            {
                dataFrom: 'keys',
                anchor: 'bottom-right',
                direction: 'column',
                justify: false,
                translateX: 120,
                translateY: 0,
                itemsSpacing: 2,
                itemWidth: 100,
                itemHeight: 20,
                itemDirection: 'left-to-right',
                itemOpacity: 0.85,
                symbolSize: 20,
                effects: [
                    {
                        on: 'hover',
                        style: {
                            itemOpacity: 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]}
        role="application"
        ariaLabel="Nivo bar chart demo"
        barAriaLabel={function(e){return e.id+": "+e.formattedValue+" in country: "+e.indexValue}}
    />
    </div>
  )
}

export default BarChart
```

Without specifying the `height`, nothing renders but by specifying the height, from the browser console I get the error:

```
nivo-bar.es.js:477 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at e (nivo-bar.es.js:477:1)
    at pe (nivo-bar.es.js:615:1)
    at ye (nivo-bar.es.js:748:1)
    at ke (nivo-bar.es.js:917:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16317:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:19987:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21457:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4113:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4162:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4224:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27244:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26380:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26290:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26259:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25556:1)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:260:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:234:1)
    at performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:518:1)
    at run (setImmediate.js:48:1)
    at runIfPresent (setImmediate.js:83:1)
    at onGlobalMessage (setImmediate.js:125:1)
```

What am I missing? I should also mention I have used the line chart and pie chart from nivo and they render. Below is a list of my dependencies form `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nivo/bar": "^0.80.0",
    "@nivo/core": "^0.80.0",
    "@nivo/line": "^0.80.0",
    "@nivo/pie": "^0.80.0",
    "@nivo/radar": "^0.80.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "react-select": "^5.7.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Comment: Try to copy code from their example. I had similar problems and I solved them by coping code and adding my stuff. As I can see by the error you are setting the wrong parameter somewhere. Go one by one.

Comment: The thing is I copied the code exactly, it didn't work that's why I added the height

Comment: Did you copy data as well? Where do you pass data to BarChart?

Comment: Yes I did add the data

Comment: barAriaLabel is the only one that seems tricky. as i said try removing property one by one